# Display title with link when sending url in messenger

Tags: javascript, angular, facebook, metadata, facebook-messenger

I have a website built in angular 5 that uses a unique value in the url to pull in data based on the value.

ex) http://url.com/:id/videos

When sending this link over facebook messenger the metadata passes the title and shows it in a preview under the link. I changed the value of the title, and this has changed the preview for all the :id values except one that had be sent over messenger before the code was updated

ex) http://url.com/john/videos
title = "John's Site"

http://url.com/smith/videos
title = "OLD OUTDATED TITLE"

Is there a cache system or CDN built into messenger that needs to be cleared so the "smith" link will show the correct title, or am I missing something in my code that would prevent only one dynamic link to from updating?

UPDATE:
Facebook's debugger says I am missing the og:title. I have added this to my head tag

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Smith's Site" />
```

but I still get the same bug "Missing og:title"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that it's possible to manually do this in this url: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

You can paste there the url and then fetch new information. Maybe there is an API or a service fot this, but I have never looked after.

Comment: using the debugger, it shows where it scrapes data from and the old title doesn't appear at all, but the preview still shows the old title

Comment: @bjwhip Hit the "scrape again" button.